# ReplaceText processor - replace \r\n with just \n

Tags: apache-nifi

GetTwitter processor returns flow file with \r\n (\0D\0A) at the end. I am building Elasticsearch bulk insert file (using MergeContent Processor) and need to replace \r\n just with \n (\0A). Otherwise I am getting error back from ES.
I am thinking to use ReplaceText processor but not sure what to use as a search and replace parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It appears elasticsearch can ingest JSON.  The data returned from the Apache NiFi GetTwitter processor is valid JSON.  What is the error being returned when posting the JSON document to ElasticSearch?  What technique are you using to post to ElasticSearch?

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Hi Joe, 
Yes, ES can ingest single document returned from GetTwitter processor. It is the problem when I try to construct a request for bulk index post.
This is how I construct the bulk post:
{ "index":  { "_index": "mergetest", "_type": "tweets"}}
{"created_at":"Mon Dec 14 15:15:02 +0000 2015","id":676420138284032000,"id_str":"676420138284032000",... tweet body}
{"created_at":"Mon Dec 14 15:15:04 +0000 2015","id":676420145103937537,"id_str":"676420145103937537",...tweet body}

The error I am getting

Comment: The error I am getting:
2015-12-14 10:16:38,764 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.PostHTTP PostHTTP[id=90bf0313-3662-4d2b-9327-682e85da9593] Failed to Post StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=90472cbf-72e7-4fbf-9b6b-d1a1c0b315da,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1450106103628-1, container=default, section=1], offset=355408, length=20236],offset=0,name=2838637922784000,size=20236] to http://myserver:9200/_bulk: response code was 400:Bad Request

Comment: Igor ah i think i see.  Are you simply doing MergeContent with binary.concatenation ?  Be sure to use the header, demarcator, footer settings of merge content so when it combines JSON documents into a new merged document that whole thing is still valid JSON (as an array of documents).